# New to C# from JS/Python... How to do Duck Typing in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a video game using C# (and the Unity engine). It's a game with a lot of guns, and here's how I'm planning to architect it...

I've got a Gun base class. This handles all the common stuff like how many shots per second can you fire, how much ammo do you have, etc.

Then I've got a bunch of one-off gun classes that inherit from this base class. A machine gun might fire a few shots and then delay, so that's a subclass. A flame thrower might set the ground on fire, so that's a subclass... etc.

Then, way over on the other side of my codebase, I've got a joystick controller.

My plan was to pass a gun instance to my joystick controller. The joystick says "hey gun, fire this way." The gun takes care of everything else.

The problem is, C# is strictly typed. So what do I do? My guns are different enough that they are different classes, so I can't tell my joystick which gun to allocate memory for.

What am I missing here? In JS or Python I'd just pass the gun in, and the language wouldn't care that the type is a subclass, because it still has a "fire" method... Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: C# doesn't have duck-typing. You can use inheritance and polymorphism. Create an asbtract superclass for all guns and use that.

Comment: For Unity, I recommend using an interface for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# and many other languages, you [implement an interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) or [create a subclass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

Comment: Go the interface route. That way you can make unit tests that check if things are working.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing here? In JS or Python I'd just pass the gun in, and the language wouldn't care that the type is a subclass, because it still has a "fire" method... Thoughts?

The base class should either have its own virtual fire method that is overridden by the child classes, or it should define an abstract method (which forces any child class to implement it). Alternatively, you can create an interface and then your controller class can use any class that implements that interface.